# How to split time range into Array of weeks?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, time

How to divide a given time period into a list of weeks starting from the beginning of the period?

for example, I have:

```
from: 2020-07-27T08:08:20.794Z,
to: 2020-09-24T08:08:20.794Z
```

the weeks must be like this:

```
27.07.2020 - 03.08.2020
04.08.2020 - 11.08.2020
12.08.2020 - 19.08.2020
20.08.2020 - 27.08.2020
28.08.2020 - 04.09.2020
05.09.2020 - 12.09.2020
13.09.2020 - 20.09.2020
21.09.2020 - 24.09.2020
```

I try with this code:

```
function getWeeksInMonth(month, year){
   var weeks=[],
       firstDate=new Date(year, month, 1),
       lastDate=new Date(year, month+1, 0), 
       numDays= lastDate.getDate();
   
   var start=1;
   var end=7-firstDate.getDay();
   while(start<=numDays){
       weeks.push({start:start,end:end});
       start = end + 1;
       end = end + 7;
       if(end>numDays)
           end=numDays;    
   }        
    return weeks;
}
```

but it returns me only with provided `month` and `year`.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

Going from from date to to date with incomplete weeks when from starts after Monday and/or to ends before a Sunday

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
const testDays = "sun,mo,tu,we,thu,fri,sat".split(",")
const makeDate = d => `${pad(d.getDate())}.${pad(d.getMonth()+1)}.${d.getFullYear()}`;

let from = new Date("2020-07-29T08:08:20.794Z");
const to = new Date("2020-09-23T08:08:20.794Z");
const aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const aWeek = 7 * aDay;
const weeks = [];
const testArr = []
for (let i = from.getTime(), n = to.getTime(); i <= n; i += aDay) {
  const d = new Date(i);
  if (d.getDay() === 1 || weeks.length === 0) { // from OR monday
    weeks.push([makeDate(d)]);
    testArr.push([testDays[d.getDay()]])
  }
  else if (d.getDay()===0 || i===n) {
    weeks[weeks.length-1].push(makeDate(d))
    testArr[testArr.length-1].push(testDays[d.getDay()])
  }  
}
weeks.forEach((week,i) => console.log(`${week[0]} - ${week[1]}`,testArr[i].join("-")))
```

This version will just add a week regardless i.e. from

```
Monday to Sunday or
Sunday to Saturday 
Saturday to Friday
Friday to Thursday
Thursday to Wednesday
Wednesday to Tuesday
Tuesday to Monday
```

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
const testDays = "sun,mo,tu,we,thu,fri,sat".split(",")
const makeDate = d => `${pad(d.getDate())}.${pad(d.getMonth()+1)}.${d.getFullYear()}`;

let from = new Date("2020-07-29T08:08:20.794Z");
const to = new Date("2020-09-23T08:08:20.794Z");
const aDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const aWeek = 7 * aDay;
const weeks = [];
const testArr = []
for (let i = from.getTime(), n = to.getTime(); i <= n; i += aWeek) {
  const d1 = makeDate(new Date(i))
  let d2 = i+aWeek-aDay;
  if (d2 > n) d2 = n;
  d2 = makeDate(new Date(d2))
  weeks.push([d1,d2]);
  
}

weeks.forEach((week,i) => console.log(`${week[0]} - ${week[1]}`))
```

Comment: ok, but when i change a `from` date to for example `29.07`, my array start from this `'03.08.2020', '09.08.2020'` week instead of `29.07.2020 - ...`

Comment: it can't start only on monday :/

Comment: I have updated to start from the Monday on or before the date your pass

Comment: week must start from the `from` date, so, if i have `from=29.07.2020`, week must be `29.07.2020-4.08.2020`

Comment: `29.07.2020 - 02.08.2020` instead of `29.07.2020 - 04.08.2020`, in the next this same issue

Comment: 4.8 is a tuesday

Comment: I have added a version that ignores what start and end day is

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to just increase the date by 7 days until there are no more days left.

```js
const from = new Date("2020-07-27T08:08:20.794Z");
const to = new Date("2020-09-24T08:08:20.794Z");

// Convert date string to dd/mm/yyyy format
const buildDateString = (date) => {
  const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  
  return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
}

// Increase date by x amount of days
const increaseDays = (date, amount) => new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + amount));

// Get all weeks in given period
const buildWeeks = (start, end) => {
  const weeks = [];
  let current = new Date(start);
  
  while(current < end) {
    // Get start of the week
    const beginOfWeek = new Date(current);
    // Get end of the week
    let endOfWeek = increaseDays(current, 6);
    // If there are less then 7 days left before the end, use the end.
    endOfWeek = endOfWeek > end ? end : endOfWeek;
    
    // Add week to our collection
    weeks.push([buildDateString(beginOfWeek), buildDateString(endOfWeek)]);
    
    current = increaseDays(current, 1);
  }
  
  return weeks;
}

const weeks = buildWeeks(from, to);

weeks.forEach(([start, end]) => console.log(`${start} - ${end}`));
```

**Without comments**

```js
const from = new Date("2020-07-27T08:08:20.794Z");
const to = new Date("2020-09-24T08:08:20.794Z");

const buildDateString = (date) => {
  const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  
  return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
}

const increaseDays = (date, amount) => new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + amount));

const buildWeeks = (start, end) => {
  const weeks = [];
  let current = new Date(start);
  
  while(current < end) {
    const beginOfWeek = new Date(current);
    let endOfWeek = increaseDays(current, 6);
    endOfWeek = endOfWeek > end ? end : endOfWeek;
    
    weeks.push([buildDateString(beginOfWeek), buildDateString(endOfWeek)]);
    current = increaseDays(current, 1);
  }
  
  return weeks;
}

const weeks = buildWeeks(from, to);
weeks.forEach(([start, end]) => console.log(`${start} - ${end}`));
```

**Typescript variant**

```js
const from = new Date("2020-07-27T08:08:20.794Z");
const to = new Date("2020-09-24T08:08:20.794Z");

const buildDateString = (date: Date) => {
  const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  
  return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
}

const increaseDays = (date: Date, amount: number) => new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + amount));

const buildWeeks = (start: Date, end: Date) => {
  const weeks = [];
  let current = new Date(start);
  
  while(current < end) {
    const beginOfWeek = new Date(current);
    let endOfWeek = increaseDays(current, 6);
    endOfWeek = endOfWeek > end ? end : endOfWeek;
    
    weeks.push([buildDateString(beginOfWeek), buildDateString(endOfWeek)]);
    current = increaseDays(current, 1);
  }
  
  return weeks;
}

const weeks = buildWeeks(from, to);
weeks.forEach(([start, end]) => console.log(`${start} - ${end}`));
```

Comment: 4.8.2020 is a Tuesday

Comment: @mplungjan good catch! I was following his output, put those weeks are 8 days long. All fixed now

Comment: can you tell me why in ts, `const increaseDays = (date, amount) => new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + amount));` return me error: `date.getDate is not a function`?

Comment: @nowymailhaha I don't know, it should work since `date` is of type Date. So as long as you describe it as `const increaseDays = (date: Date, amount: number)` it should work.

Comment: in TS you must add `let endDate = new Date(end);`